# Bigquery- Declaring an array from list of Integers

Tags: google-bigquery

I am trying to declare a list of integers as a variable named `list_of_ints`.  My code works, but it seems to be a bit of a workaround:

```
DECLARE list_of_ints ARRAY <INT64>;
set list_of_ints = (
  SELECT ARRAY_AGG( DISTINCT some_ints)
  FROM (SELECT * FROM UNNEST ([11,22,33]) as some_ints) 
);
```

I was hoping for something along the lines of

```
DECLARE list_of_ints ARRAY <INT64>;
set list_of_ints = ARRAY([11,22,33]);
```

but it seems that this is improper syntax. Is there a way akin to the above attempt to declare an array as a variable in bigquery?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use below

```
DECLARE list_of_ints ARRAY <INT64>;
SET list_of_ints = [11,22,33];
```

OR

```
DECLARE list_of_ints ARRAY <INT64> DEFAULT [11,22,33]
```